# php domdocument creates self closing tag that breaks html

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm parsing user input text & converting youtube urls into an iframe using a regex so I end up with the following:

```
<iframe title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="370" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/*id*" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The text is then parsed through `DOMdocument()` which converts the above into a self closing tag:

```
<iframe class="EmbeddedVideo" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="370" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xP4HhaUMB3I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""/>
```

Which breaks the page in Chrome & Opera. If I manually change the html back to:

```
<iframe class="EmbeddedVideo" title="YouTube video player" width="640" height="370" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xP4HhaUMB3I" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

it works.

Firstly, is there anything wrong with the self closing tag (because I can't see anything)?

Is there a way to force domdocument() to use a 'proper' closing tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the option [`LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php):

```
$doc->saveXML($node, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

This will force expanding `<iframe />` to `<iframe></iframe>`

However, you can also use `saveHTML()` (which is preferred). This will preserve HTML tags properly:

```
$doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: This breaks tags like `<br />`

Comment: Does it really `break` them? I assume `<br></br>` is valid. Isn't it?

Comment: From what I can see, the browser is interpreting it as two line breaks :(

Comment: @JamesHalsall I needed to get into this post again. The question was about a single snippet of HTML containing the `<iframe>` node (not about a whole page). If you want to save a whole HTML document, then use `saveHTML()` instead. It will preserve tags properly and produce valid HTML. (It could be also used here, will add that)

Comment: A better fix would actually be instead to just add `->textContent` to `<iframe>` tags in the content. This forces the XML parser to output `</iframe>` since content is now present inside of the tag. For example: Iterate over `$doc->getElementsByTagName('iframe')` and then call `$el->textContent = 'This content requires IFrames to be enabled.';`.

Comment: Well, I take that back. I ended up with additional bugs/issues relating to empty `<span>` tags that were being self-closed by the parser. ‍♂️

Comment: @patricknelson 's comment setting iframe textContent should get more attention. Thanks for the quick fix.

Comment: Right @sglessard, I see my fix is actually still perfect for this specific use case, so hopefully my "take that back" response doesn't confuse anyone! I happened to also be doing a lot more than just parsing `<iframe>` which was why I still got stuck at the time.